# Why is the image from PointGray camera displaying in grayscale?

Tags: ros, camera-driver, pointgrey

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm pulling an image stream from a PointGrey camera using the [FlyCapture SDK](https://www.ptgrey.com/flycapture-sdk). When I display the camera feed in PointGrey's FlyCap2, the image displays in color, but when I look at the feed in RVIZ (or export the bag to jpg) it shows grayscale images. How should I address this?

[Script for getting image and publishing to ROS topic](https://github.com/CPFL/Autoware/blob/master/ros/src/sensing/drivers/camera/packages/pointgrey/nodes/grasshopper3/grasshopper3.cpp)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269284/why-is-the-image-from-pointgray-camera-displaying-in-grayscale?/) by [ckirksey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29364/ckirksey/) on ROS Answers with karma: 203 on 2017-08-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on 2017-08-21**:
Please edit your question to show the exact command you are running to view the image (or which topic you are using in rviz) and which topics are available. My suspicion is that you are not looking at the color image topic, but without more information it is difficult to provide an answer.

**Comment by [ckirksey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29364/ckirksey/) on 2017-08-22**:
I'm getting the `image_raw` camera topic that's published by the referenced script. The raw image is coming over from the FlyCapture SDK in the bayer_gbrg8 encoding format

**Comment by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on 2017-08-25**:
Do you see any topics such as `image_color` or `image_rect_color`? You probably need to run a node like [image_proc](http://wiki.ros.org/image_proc) to convert your raw images and calibration info (`sensor_msgs/CameraInfo`) to color/rectified images.

**Comment by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on 2017-08-25**:
FYI, eventually you will need a separate calibration message (`sensor_msgs/CameraInfo`) per camera. Right now you have an array of images (one for each detected camera) but only a single calibration message being published.

**Comment by [ckirksey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29364/ckirksey/) on 2017-08-29**:
image_proc did the trick! Thanks. I used this gist to publish `CameraInfo` for each camera from the yaml config file: https://gist.github.com/rossbar/ebb282c3b73c41c1404123de6cea4771

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do you see any topics such as `image_color` or `image_rect_color`? You probably need to run a node like [image_proc](http://wiki.ros.org/image_proc) to convert your raw images and calibration info (`sensor_msgs/CameraInfo`) to color/rectified images.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2017-08-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1